# mysqli_assoc + json_encode does not return first row

Tags: php, json, mysqli

```
$sql= "SELECT team_name AS label, user_id as value
FROM d_getreal_captains ORDER BY team_name ASC";
$result = $bfit_connect->query($sql);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
    $json[] = $rows;
}
```

This code works as expected except it does not return the first record from the table (i.e. the first team_name and user_id).  I have seen that other people have suggested the fix of using mysql_data_seek to reset the row index, but I also know that is deprecated and would like my fix to be utilizing a current method.  And ideas or advice is appreciated... thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` outside of your loop which is popping the first result off of the result set. You aren't using the values anywhere so you can safely remove it.

```
$result = $bfit_connect->query($sql);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); // <-- remove this
```

Comment: Thank you.  I thought if I removed that line that I wouldn't be able to run my json loop because I didn't have the $rows variable; silly though because I see that I'm actually defining it twice.  Thank you for your prompt response.

Comment: not as prompt as mine, but I guess he definitely needs some points :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql= "SELECT team_name AS label, user_id as value
FROM d_getreal_captains ORDER BY team_name ASC";
$result = $bfit_connect->query($sql);
//Here you used to take the first row out with mysqli_fetch_assoc, I removed this line   

while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
    $json[] = $rows;
}
```